# Java IO Exception for a Web Based CSV Export

Tags: java, browser, io

I have 'download to csv' link on one of my reporting webpages and the typical output for the .csv file is about 4MB which typically takes around 5 minutes to complete running the query and serving results using a single thread.

One of the users continues to run into this issue:

[com.jspbook.GZIPResponseWrapper:finishResponse] Exception :java.io.IOException: This output stream has already been closed

There is also a reference to a broken pipe exception in the server logs.

When the user runs into this error I notice from the server's perspective everything completes on time.

For the user the export link spins infinite and never returns the data.

What causes this issue and is there a way to persist the connection with the browser?

Comment: What's the browser timeout value?

Comment: The browser does not timeout, it continues to spin as if it is fetching results.  The user run IE which times out at 1 hour of not receiving a reponse.

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection timeout setting of your server. Waiting for 5 minutes is a long time.

Looks like the connection is timed out or broken. Server tries to write to the response when your query finishes but the connection is already closed.

If the generation cannot be made faster then look to push to user when file is available via **web socket or continuous polling** from client.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to answer by @Bhushan Bhangale-

If the server takes a long time to respond, the connection is closed. So in such cases where the processing takes a long time (to create a response), one of the options is-

1. When you get a request, start 2 threads on the server
2. One is a sort-of timer that comes out just 2-3 seconds before the timeout interval
3. The other one that actually fires a query to the database and creates a .csv file

Remember, the main thread which got the request has to wait till it is notified by one of the threads started above. This may not be a good practice but in some odd scenarios, there's no other choice.

Now,
1. If the first (timer) thread completes before the response is ready, it just sets a flag, and gives back a message to the user that the server is still processing the request
2. For the second thread, there could be two conditions-
   a. The response (.csv file) is ready before the flag is set by the first thread, so it just sends back the response (file) and cancels the timer (first) thread
   b. If it finds that the flag is set (which means that the response is already sent), it either ignores the response (may be delete a file) or send the file via email (if such functionality can be incorporated)

These threads cannot send back the response themselves, they have to notify the main thread which will send the response to the user. You need to set the appropriate flags / values so that the main thread knows the type of response to send.

Hope this helps.